# Kentico & CMSForm: Load a different form after page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, kentico, document-types

Using Kentico 7, I have a cms form on the aspx page like so:

```
<cms:CMSForm runat="server" ID="cmsFormCreate"
    FormMode="Insert" ShowOkButton="false"
    ParentNodeID='<%# documentsFolderNodeID %>'
/>
```

On the backend, I'm setting the form's parent node id (so I have a base location to save to which I will change later.

I get the form/document name by calling

```
CMS.SettingsProvider.DataClassInfoProvider.GetClasses("*", "className LIKE '%MyDocument.%'", "", Integer.MaxValue).Tables(0).Rows
```

That returns a dataset which I negotiate for the document name, class id (if I ever need it) and so forth.

I want to change the form that is loaded on postback. That is to say that I have several document types in the CMS Site Manager and I want to swap between them. I want to display one on page load (this works fine). However, when I fire the mechanism to change the form which is displayed (dropdown list OnSelectedIndexChanged), it fails to load the new form.

```
Private Sub PopulateCMSForm(ByRef targetForm As CMS.FormControls.CMSForm, sourceDDL As ListItem)       
    targetForm.FormName = sourceDDL.Value
    'targetForm.LoadForm() 'same results with or without this
End Sub
```

I have verified that the form I expect shows up correctly by hard coding the form name (Document type code name) and the form will display just fine the first time the page loads.

*How do I manage to change the empty/blank document type that the CMS Form object is loading on post-back?*

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
Private Sub PopulateCMSForm(ByRef targetForm As CMS.FormControls.CMSForm, sourceDDL As ListItem)       
    targetForm.FormName = sourceDDL.Value
    targetForm.LoadForm(True) 
End Sub
```

**True** value as an argument of the method **LoadForm** should force reload of the form.

Comment: Which does not work since Loading the form causes an error saying that a class was not specified for the node. This behavior implies that LoadForm(true) is to load existing data and not a form template ready for new data.

Comment: Could you give us an example, what value is set to the FormName property? Is it in valid form/class name format?

Comment: In this particular instance, the form display name is being set to `MyDocument.State#GA-Document`. The code name is set to `MyDocument_State.GA_Document`. Of course, you set the form name to the display name. The document does exist in the the document types of Site Manager and loads using form name (`MyDocument.State#GA-Document`) correctly the first time the page is loaded.